# Initializing C# Project in git

Tags: c#, git, gitignore

I have made a C# Project and Initialized it via git bash shell.Now we know that git should be only tracking source files for that I have added a .gitignore file and in it typed the following regular expressions.

```
!*.cs
!*.resx
```

Then I committed my .gitignore file My question is that Is my approach right?

Comment: you should also track your project files. Search in internet and you'll find many .gitignore templates for c# projects.

Comment: Just ignore files you actually want to ignore; you can always decide to ignore another file type, once you have encountered it. Otherwise, you will just end up missing valuable things.

Answer (score 2):

That seems woefully incomplete - we recommend that you add your project files (`.csproj`) to version control as well.  You would also want to add any resources that are required.  In fact, it's much easier to *exclude* the files you don't want, like temporary files and user-specific data, rather than trying to *include* the files you do want.

As a result, we recommend that you use the community's [`VisualStudio.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file as the `.gitignore` for Visual Studio projects.

If you use Visual Studio to initialize your repository, it will add this file for you.